# Corodva app icon wont change

Tags: cordova, icons

I am having an issue with changing app icon in ios/android in cordova project.

I put icon src="icon.png" inside widget tag in config.xml.
Icon is inside my root folder. I got an error if i
execute following command:

```
cordova run ios
```

error:

> The following build commands failed:
>           CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/Survival\ Guide.app Survival\ Guide/Images.xcassets (1 failure) Error: Error code 65 for
>   command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/andreasplado/Desktop/work/studyinestoniaapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Survival
>   Guide.xcworkspace,-scheme,Survival
>   Guide,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
>   Simulator,name=iPhone
>   X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/andreasplado/Desktop/work/studyinestoniaapp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/andreasplado/Desktop/work/studyinestoniaapp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Please help me to change the icon of an app!
Looking forward to hear from you soon.

Comment: Have you executed a `cordova prepare` before running the app?

Answer (score 0):

All latest cordova versions ideally expects (based on supported versions) the icons to have all 1x, 2x and 3x images with proper naming. You can refer [Cordova App Icons](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html)  for better understanding. Please cross-check your code with this link.